# how to convert kotlin set to java in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

There is kotlin set code as following:

```
val CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED =
 setOf<CustomCity>(CustomCity.MUNICH, CustomCity.BERLIN, CustomCity.SAIGON, 
 CustomCity.TESTMUNICH, CustomCity.TBILISI)
```

I want to convert that code to java What would be its equivalent java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set<CustomCity> CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED = new HashSet<>(
    Arrays.asList(
        CustomCity.MUNICH, 
        CustomCity.BERLIN,
        CustomCity.SAIGON,
        CustomCity.TESTMUNICH,
        CustomCity.TBILISI
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<CustomCity> CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED = new HashSet<CustomCity>

CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED.add(CustomCity.MUNICH);
CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED.add(CustomCity.BERLIN);
CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED.add(CustomCity.TESTMUNICH);
CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED.add( CustomCity.TBILISI);
 //TO print your set:
SYstem.out.println(CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLED);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the constructors.

```
Set<CustomCity> CITIES_WITH_LOGIN_ENABLES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(CustomCity.MUNICH, CustomCity.BERLIN, CustomCity.SAIGON, CustomCity.TESTMUNICH, CustomCity.TBILISI));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its equivalent to Java `Set` if you look into definition of `setOf()` Its immutable set containing only the specified object and the set is serializable.

You can check `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode > Decompile`.

You can use `HashSet` its serialized (Watch out for type)

```
Set<CustomCity> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(CustomCity.MUNICH,CustomCity.TBILISI));
```